# Proof of Borel-Carathetheodory Inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for a hint (whole solutions are boring) for the prove of the following inequality. $D(0)$ is the circle with Radius $R$.

Suppose $f(0) = 0$. Let $r < R$ and $f$ analytic in a neighborhood of $D(0).$

$$\max_{|z|=r} f(z) \leq \frac{4r}{R-r} \max_{|z|=R} \operatorname{Re} f(z)$$

Thank you for your help and I'm sorry for my poor skills in MathJax.

Comment: Poisson integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:
Use Scwarz integral representation (Poisson integral)$$
f(z)=i\operatorname{Im }f(0)+\frac{1}{2\pi R}\int_{|\zeta |=R}\frac{\zeta -z}{\zeta +z}\operatorname{Re }f(\zeta )\,|d\zeta |.$$

Hint 2:
Let $A=\max_{|z|=R} \operatorname{Re} f(z)$ and consider $$g(z)=\frac{Rf(z)}{f(z)-2A}.$$
Show that $g(0)=0$ and $|g(z)|<R$ in $D(0)$. Then we can apply Schwarz lemma to $g$ to get $$
\left|\frac{Rf(z)}{f(z)-2A}\right|\le |z|.$$
This leads to $$
R|f(z)|\le r|f(z)|+2rA$$
for $|z|=r$.